# limit actions PHP

Tags: php

Basically, I have a function that returns a total amount of "items" inside of a database, The limit on these items is **40**, If the returned value is less than **40** i want it to perform actions thus increasing the the limit by **1** until it reaches **40** again, after that i want it to stop, The code i'm currently using is shown below

```
$count = $row['COUNT'];
foreach($result as $row) {
    if($count < 40) {
       //I want to execute a function, thus increasing the $count by one evertime
       //until it reaches 40, after that it must stop
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use += to increment count. When count is > 40 then use  `break;` to immediately stop the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = $row['COUNT'];
foreach($result as $row) {
    if($count >= 40) {
       break; // exit foreach loop immediately
    }
    //put code here
    $count += 1; // or whatever you want it to be incremented by, e.g. $row['COUNT']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want a `while` loop. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

```
$count = $row['COUNT'];
foreach($result as $row) {
    while($count < 40) {
       //Execute the function that increases the count
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function custom_action(&$count) {
    while($count++ < 40) {
          // do some cool stuff...
          $count++;
    }
}

$count = $row['COUNT'];
foreach($result as $row) {
    if($count < 40) {
        custom_action($count);
    }
}
```